# R code to determine peakedness of a maximum

Tags: r, algorithm

Given input vector `x`, let the maximum of `x` occur at index `i` in the input vector. I am trying to quantify the peakedness of this maximum and do that I have thought of determining following quantities. I am interested in determining numbers `l` and `r` such that:

```
x[i-l] < x[i-l+1] < ... < x[i-1] < x[i] but x[i-l-1] >= x[i-l]
```

and similarly:

```
x[i+r] < x[i+r-1] < ... < x[i+1] < x[i] but x[i+r+1] >= x[i+r]
```

What would be an efficient way of doing this in R? Also how can I generalize this in R so that if input is a matrix `M` then above procedure is applied independently to each column of `M`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should play with `rle` and `cumsum` of boolean vectors. The following function finds `l` :

```
left.peak <- function(x) {
    gt = (x[-1] > x[-length(x)])
    gt.rle = rle(gt)
    sum.rle = cumsum(gt.rle$len * gt.rle$val)
    sum.rle = c(0, sum.rle[-length(sum.rle)])
    c(0, cumsum(gt) - rep(sum.rle, gt.rle$len))
}
```

to find `r`, reverse `x`, call `left.peak`, then reverse `x` again.

Comment: could you put some comments in this code? its too hard to understand

Comment: just run it line by line